# Monotonic increasing of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

So my question is that if the limit of a sequence goes to infinity, does this sequence have to be increasing?

Comment: No. Let $a_n=n$ if $n$ is even and $a_n=2n$ if $n$ is odd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't, it could for example still go up and down while still having a general trend towards infinity - as an example, think about a sequence $(a_n)$ that is equal to $n$ for even $n$ and $n - 2$ for odd $n$. Since we always have $(a_n) \geq n - 2$ this sequence goes to infinity, but it is neither increasing nor decreasing, since for odd $n$ we have $n - 2 = a_n < a_{n+1} = n+1$, but for even $n$ we have $n = a_n > a_{n+1} = n - 1$.

Comment: How do you precisely determine the sequence goes to infinity?

Comment: Well, divergence, so "going to infinity" is defined as the sequence eventually rising above every possible upper bound and staying there, more formally that for every $S \in \mathbb R$ there exists a $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_n > S$ for all $n>N$. Since we always have $a_n > n - 2$ it is easy to verify that any $N$ above $S + 2$ serves our purpose, which means that the sequence must go to infinity by definition

Answer (score 0):

Not of course, let consider

$$a_n= n+2\cos (\pi n)=-1,4,1,6,3,8,5,10,7,...\quad a_n\to \infty$$

Indeed, more in general, any bounded sequence which oscillates (regularly or irregularly) around a value which tends to infinity will satisfy the definition

$$\forall M \quad \exists \bar n: \quad n>\bar n \implies \quad a_n>M$$